# The page loge me out when refresh. React router dom. Protected routes

Tags: javascript, authentication, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm doing a react-redux web app where I need to have some protected routes, I have seen a lot of tutorials of how to do it but they do not work with the new version of react-router-dom, I feel I'm very close to achieving it, but there is something that does not work, when I refresh the page I set the auth value to false and I have to loge in again, how can I solve it? here is my code.

useAuth.js file.

```
import React from "react";

const authContext = React.createContext();

function useAuth() {
  const [authed, setAuthed] = React.useState(false);

  return {
    authed,
    login() {
      return new Promise((res) => {
        setAuthed(true);
        console.log("entro en la auth")
        res();
      });
    },
    logout() {
      return new Promise((res) => {
        setAuthed(false);
        res();
      });
    }
  };
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const auth = useAuth();

  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={auth}>
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function AuthConsumer() {
  return React.useContext(authContext);
}
```

RequireAuth.js file.

```
import useAuth from './useAuth';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router';

export default function RequireAuth({ children }) {
    const { authed } = useAuth();
    console.log(authed)
    
    return  (
        authed === true ? children : <Navigate to='/' replace/>
)

}
```

Login page.

```
import React from "react";
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import {GoogleLogin} from 'react-google-login'; 
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router'
import { accepted, getUserInfo } from "../../Redux/Actions";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import useAuth from '../Auth/useAuth'


export default function Login(){

    const navigate = useNavigate(); 
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {login} = useAuth(); 

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log("token" , token)

    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
        if(!response.hasOwnProperty('error')){
        login().then(()=>{
            var body = {
            id: response.profileObj.googleId,
            name: response.profileObj.givenName,
            mail: response.profileObj.email,
            image: response.profileObj.imageUrl
        }
        dispatch(getUserInfo(body))
        navigate('/home/'+ body.id) }) 
    }
        else {alert(response.error)}
      }
    return(
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem', backgroundColor: "#1CB842" }}>
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>Inicia sesion con google</Card.Title>
                <GoogleLogin
                 clientId="googleclientIdXD"
                 buttonText="Login"
                 onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                 onFailure={responseGoogle}
                 cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
               />
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

App page

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <AuthProvider>
     <Routes>
       <Route exact path = '/' element={<Landing/>}/>
       <Route path = '/home/:id' element={<RequireAuth><Home/></RequireAuth>}/>
       <Route path = '/proyecto/:id/:proyecto' element={<Proyecto/>}/>
       <Route path = '/proyecto/form/:id/:proyecto/' element={<FormProyecto/>}/>
       <Route path = '/bug/:id/:proyecto/:bug' element={<Bug/>}/>
     </Routes>
    </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You reset the `authed` state to `false` when the code mounts, and don't persist the auth state anywhere to retrieve after a page reload.

Persist the `authed` state to localStorage when it updates, and initialize it from localStorage.

```
function useAuth() {
  const [authed, setAuthed] = React.useState(
    () =>  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authed')) ?? false
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('authed', JSON.stringify(authed));
  }, [authed]);

  return {
    authed,
    login() {
      return new Promise((res) => {
        setAuthed(true);
        console.log("entro en la auth")
        res();
      });
    },
    logout() {
      return new Promise((res) => {
        setAuthed(false);
        res();
      });
    }
  };
}
```

You'll also want to move the `authed` state into the context provider and use the `useAuth` hook to access the context's value. This is so all `useAuth` hooks reference the same singular state.

useAuth.js

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [authed, setAuthed] = React.useState(
    () => localStorage.getItem('authed') !== null
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('authed', JSON.stringify(authed));
  }, [authed]);
  
  const value = {
    authed,
    login() {
      return new Promise((res) => {
        setAuthed(true);
        console.log("entro en la auth")
        res();
      });
    },
    logout() {
      return new Promise((res) => {
        setAuthed(false);
        res();
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'll try like this, thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, I did and it worked.